# How to clear cell if formula returns blank value?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a formula like this:

```
 if(A1="","",1)
```

How do I do a quick search to remove the formula if it is `""`?
I tried searching for blanks, but because there is a formula, it does not return a blank.

Comment: isn't it a space and not a blank?  alternately, you could set it to some unique character, like `"@"` or `"|"` and then search for that character and delete all matches

Comment: Or you could filter on the column for `" "` and delete all results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the following code

```
Sub ClearCell()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 10
        If Rng.Cells(i,1) = "" Then
           Rng.Cells(i,1).ClearContents
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

That will leave the cell truly `EMPTY` and not with a zero-character `""` string.

If you are looking to clear arbitrary length whitespace in cells, use

```
If Len(Trim(Rng.Cells(i,1))) = 0 Then
' .....
```

This condition will be true for any number of spaces or no spaces (empty string). That way (almost) anything which looks blank will get cleared.

Comment: What if you had a formula that returned "".  This wouldn't work as the cell contains the formula.  I just want to display all my cells together so I can read them and not scroll through the 288000 lines of code.  My formula is: =IF(E13<30,CONCATENATE(A13,B13,C13,"-",TEXT(D13,"hh:mm:ss"),"-",E13),"")

Comment: What's the exact question? The above solution solves the given question here

Comment: Created my own simplified question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29087853/excel-delete-rows-if-formula-returns